# Nuget offline package install doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am working on a pc that doesn`t have an internet connection.
I tried to access the system.DirectoryServicies.AccountManagement nuget package, but I had to install it offline. I downloaded the 6.0.0 version and did the following link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25127.nuget-offline-package.aspx. It shows the package when I browse it, but when I try to install it, it says:

"Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
An error occured while sending the request.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'".

Is there any to pass the service load?

Comment: In the link you present, there is a check box left of the online nuget feed. Does it help to disable it?

Comment: @Fabian it actually worked, yet is says that it is unable to find packages that I don`t know about.

Comment: One nuget package can depend on other nuget packages. You can find these packages by either investigating the dependency tree of your project in VS or, by looking at the 'obj/project.assets.json' file.

Comment: @Fabian and is there any way to download the entire dependency tree? Or do you have to install them one by one

Comment: If you install the package somewhere, all the dependencies will be downloaded into your local nuget package cache. By default it can be found under C:/Users/<username>/.nuget/packages but the path may be defined differently on your PC. (if it is the same PC you want to use offline, maybe it even works to set the package source to that location - just an untested idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these method:

1.Uncheck the package source: nuget.org

[image]

2.Choose package source in the top right corner of the NuGet Package Manager

[image]